Clifford Module Bundle of Exterior Algebra of Differential Forms
The definition of Clifford Module Bundle is:
A Clifford bundle over $(M, g)$ is a vector bundle $S \rightarrow M$ with connection $\nabla^S$ with the following properties:
i) for each $x \in M, S_x$ is a representation of $\operatorname{Cliff}\left(T_x M, g_x\right)$, i.e., $S$ is a bundle of Clifford representations,
ii) the connection $\nabla^S$ is compatible with the Levi-Civita connection in the following way:
$$
\nabla_X^S(Y \cdot s)=\left(\nabla_X^{\mathrm{LC}} Y\right) \cdot s+Y \cdot\left(\nabla_X^S s\right),
$$
for all $X, Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ and $s$ a section of $S$. In this equation, the $\cdot$ indicates the Clifford action of a vector field, i.e., a section of $T M \subset \operatorname{Cliff}(T M, g)$ on $S$.
I want to show that $\wedge T^* M$ is a Clifford Module Bundle. I have already shown that $\wedge T^* M$ is a module of Clifford algebra. So my question is to prove part ii). The Clifford action is given by
$$
\psi(X) \alpha:=\tilde{X} \wedge \alpha-\iota_X \alpha, \quad \text { for } \alpha \in \Omega^k(M),\quad \tilde{X}_j=X^i g_{i j}
$$
What is exactly the Clifford connection $\nabla^S$ in this case?

Should the Clifford connection not be the Levi-Civita connection?
